# Worker node execution in Apach-Strom

Tags: apache-storm, worker

Storm topology is been deployed using Storm command on machine X. Worker nodes are running on Machine Y.

Once topology has been deployed, this is ready to process tuples and workers are processing request and response.

Can anyone please suggest that how do Worker node identify work and data, as I am not sure how worker node has access of code which is not at all deployed by developer?
          If code to topology is accessible to Worker Nodes, can you please where is the location of this and also suggest execution of Worker nodes?

Answer (score 0):

One, your asking a fairly complex question. I've been using Storm for awhile and don't understand much about how it works internally. [Here](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/06/21/understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers/) is a good article talking about the internals of Storm. It's over two years old but should still be highly relevant. I believe that Netty is now used as the internal messaging transport, it's mentioned as being experimental in the article.

As far as code being run on worker nodes, there is an configuration in storm.yaml,

```
storm.local.dir
```

When uploading the Topology, I believe it copies the jar to that location. So every different worker machine will have the necessary jar in it's configured `storm.local.dir`. So even though you only upload the one machine, Storm will distributed it to the necessary workers. (That's from memory and I'm not in a spot to test it at the moment. )